# NodeJS Get request not working with Proxy (ECONREFUSED)

Tags: node.js, post, proxy, get, request

I'm trying to use NodeJS get requets using the 'request' module, so here is my code:

```
var request = require('request');
request({
  'url':'http://whatismyip.host/',
  'method': "GET",
  'proxy': 'http://181.112.225.78:35482'
},function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
  else{
      console.log(error);
  }
})
```

When I remove the "'proxy': 'http://181.112.225.78:35482'" line, it works perfectly, but when I let it, I have this error:

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 181.112.225.78:35482
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '181.112.225.78',
  port: 35482 }
```

I already tried to change the proxy, and I got the same error, so I have no idea where is it coming from...

Thanks you !

Comment: can you make sure that proxy is working first?

Comment: also make sure the port is open